# Using "needs" to createRecord in router with the need-object as property

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I want to know how to create a model in the router with a property taken from the dependency given by the "needs"-function of the controller. I'm using ember-1.0.0-rc.3.

Here is how my application looks now, a little simplified:

```
App.LeagueAddMatchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        var match = App.Match.createRecord({});
        return match;
    },
    setupController: function (controller) {
        controller.set('players', App.Player.find());
    }

});

App.LeagueAddMatchController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: "league",
    save: function () {
        this.get('model').get('transaction').commit();
        return this.transitionToRoute('leagues');
    }
});

App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('leagues', function () {
        this.resource('league', { path: ':league_id' }, function () {
            this.route('addMatch');
        })
    });
});

App.LeaguesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return App.League.find();
    }
});

App.League = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    matches: DS.hasMany('App.Match')
});

App.Match = DS.Model.extend({
    league: DS.belongsTo('App.League'),
    p1: DS.belongsTo('App.Player', {inverse: 'p1matches'}),
    p2: DS.belongsTo('App.Player', {inverse: 'p2matches'}),
    p1Score: DS.attr('number'),
    p2Score: DS.attr('number')
});
```

This is what I would want to accomplish:

```
App.LeagueAddMatchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        var match = App.Match.createRecord({league: controller.league });
        return match;
    },
    setupController: function (controller) {
        controller.set('players', App.Player.find());
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From inside a route you can access a different controller using:

```
this.controllerFor("theControllerIWant");
```

so you can do:

```
App.LeagueAddMatchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    var match = App.Match.createRecord();
    match.set('league', this.controllerFor("league"));
    return match;
  },
  setupController: function (controller) {
    controller.set('players', App.Player.find());
  }
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried it like this:

    var match = App.Match.createRecord({league: this.controllerFor("league")});

But I get an error when I try to open the route, saying:

    Attributes must be numbers, strings or booleans, not <App.League:ember577:1>

Comment: Thanks, but still not working, it says:

    You can only add a record of App.League to this relationship 

When I try changing it to:

    match.set('league', this.controllerFor("league").get('model'));

I get this error again:

    Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Attributes must be numbers, strings or booleans, not <App.League:ember294:1>

Comment: I was an idiot, there was something in my template giving the error. Your solution works :)